# Jupyter上でRを動かしたいが上手くいかない

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

下記のサイトを参考に、Jupyter上でRを使えるように何度もトライしていますが、全くうまくいきません. 下記サイト以外の全ての質問箱を閲覧しましたが、なぜうまくいっていないのかよくわかっていません.

- [JupyterでR - ryamadaのコンピュータ・数学メモ](https://ryamada.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20171115/1510731010)
- [Rの始め方 (Windows, Jupyter notebook) - YKpages](https://kato-robotics.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/03/26/171754)

おそらくJupyter NotebookをAnaconda経由でインストールしたことが足枷になっている気がするのですが、Anaconda経由でインストールしてもうまくいきませんでした.

どこから説明すれば良いかわからないので、[上記リンク２つ目](https://kato-robotics.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/03/26/171754) の通り、RGui経由で全く同じことを行いましたが以下のエラーがでてしまい、対処の仕方がよくわかりません.

力足らずで投げやりな質問に近くなってしまって申し訳ないです.  
なにかアドバイス頂けたら幸いです.
最悪, Jupyter NotebookやAnacondaを再インストールしても良い気がします.

**使用ソフト**
Windows10 (64bit)
Anaconda:5.2.0 Jupyter NotebookはAnaconda経由でインストール済み
R:3.6.1

```
> devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
Downloading GitHub repo IRkernel/IRkernel@master
"C:\PROGRA~1\Git\cmd\git.exe" clone --depth 1 --no-hardlinks --recurse-submodules https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_kernel_test.git C:\Users\reisa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpktdHtl\remotesaf82e67146b/IRkernel-IRkernel-67592db/tests/testthat/jkt
"C:\PROGRA~1\Git\cmd\git.exe" clone --depth 1 --no-hardlinks --recurse-submodules https://github.com/flying-sheep/ndjson-testrunner.git C:\Users\reisa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpktdHtl\remotesaf82e67146b/IRkernel-IRkernel-67592db/tests/testthat/njr
These packages have more recent versions available.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                             
2: CRAN packages only              
3: None                            
4: digest (0.6.21 -> 0.6.22) [CRAN]
5: rlang  (0.4.0  -> 0.4.1 ) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:

   checking for file 'C:\Users\reisa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpktdHtl\remotesaf82e67146b\IRkernel-IRkernel-67592db/DESCRIPTION' ...
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\reisa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpktdHtl\remotesaf82e67146b\IRkernel-IRkernel-67592db/DESCRIPTION'

-  preparing 'IRkernel': (540ms)
   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information

-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts

-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Removed empty directory 'IRkernel/example-notebooks'

-  building 'IRkernel_1.0.2.9000.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/reisa/OneDrive/ドキュメント/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'IRkernel' ...
** using staged installation
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  (converted from warning) cannot open file 'C:/Users/reisa/OneDrive/hLg/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-IRkernel/00new/IRkernel/DESCRIPTION': Invalid argument
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'IRkernel'
* removing 'C:/Users/reisa/OneDrive/ドキュメント/R/win-library/3.6/IRkernel'
Error: Failed to install 'IRkernel' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/reisa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpktdHtl/fileaf8738760be/IRkernel_1.0.2.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: OSの情報や、使いたいもののバージョン情報などが補助情報として書いてあると良さそうだなと思いました。　／　うまくいかないというのは、Jupyter Notebook を開いても R カーネルが表示されないということでしょうか。

Comment: そういうことです.  Rカーネルをインストールするために,devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')の宣言をRのコンソールから行う必要があるのですが、それがうまくいきません.

Comment: 全然関係無いかもしれませんが、OneDriveでは無い場所でOneDriveにはインストール元ファイル/インストール対象/プロジェクト/作業/Tmpなどのフォルダも何も関係させないようにして試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 約1年前の英語記事で、条件も違っていそうですが、こんなのがありました。[Fastest and smallest way to set up R with jupyter on Windows](https://bence.ferdinandy.com/2018/11/22/fastest-way-to-set-up-r-with-jupyter-on-windows/)

Comment: @kunif さんありがとうございます.  上記のサイトどおりに行ったところ, Jupyter上に入れることができました.  ただし、Rをインストールしているのにも関わらず、Rがインストール済みでない場合でないと入れられなかったことから、インストール先がぐちゃぐちゃになってしまった感はありますが,....

Answer (score 3):

ご質問ですが、「Rを使えるjupyter notebooksインスタンスを動かしたい」という理解でよろしければ、環境構築でつまづくことの多いWindows環境での手動ビルドではなく、「dockerコンテナ」を利用する事を強くオススメします。

docker for windows をインストールしたら、
ターミナルから

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

と打って少し待ちます。
pull / build / run が終わると、
http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
のようなログイン用URLが表示されます。google chromeでそのアドレスを開いて下さい。(IE/Edgeは使わないで下さい)

New kernel を選択すると Julia / Python / R が選べます。

データサイエンスのタスクは再現性担保の観点からも、環境のコンテナ化と素晴らしく相性が良いです。

コンテナをカスタムしたい場合は、dockerfile の書き方を調べてみてください。
カスタムコンテナの作成、デプロイが如何に便利かわかると思います。

Comment: 補足します。データサイエンス界隈でWindowsを使っていると文字コードの混乱や並列処理ライブラリ( parallel )の非互換などで足が止まることが多いです。dockerを使うと純粋な Linux 環境がどのホスト環境でも再現出来ますので、unixに慣れるのにも非常に有効です。 まず dockerfile で sudo apt install 〜 を並べて必要な環境を再現可能( reproducible ) に構築する事から慣れてみると色々な事に転用しやすいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　勉強します

Answer (score 0):

公式ページ https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel の[インストール方法解説](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/)には以下のように書かれていました。前提として、Jupyter と R がインストールされているとします。

手順1. CRAN から IRkernel をインストールする。

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
```

手順2. Jupyter からカーネルが使えるようにする。

```
IRkernel::installspec()
```

上のコマンドだと現在のユーザーにのみインストールされる。全ユーザーに対してインストールしたい場合は下のコマンドを使う。

```
IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)
```